# How do I access a file in a directory from html in a Wordpress Site?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I am trying to use reactjs components in wordpress. I was following this tutorial -

https://jhinter.medium.com/using-react-based-web-components-in-wordpress-f0d4097aca38

Until I got stuck at the last part: I have added this as an html custom block to an empty page:

```
<script src="/apps/csptest-component/direflowBundle.js"></script>
<csptest-component></csptest-component>
```

The console prints out:

> GET http://www.adminprofi.com/apps/csptest-component/direflowBundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have used FTP to put the file in a folder called apps/csptest-component in the root directory of the wordpress site and I can see that the upload was successful. Do I need to change the link that the src is pointing to? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress allows you to access files in the wp-content directory, so best practice would be to have a child theme setup and then you can upload your javascript to the directory: wp-content/themes/child/js and access it using http://www.adminprofi.com/wp-content/themes/child/js/direflowBundles.js .

It's recommended to use a child theme to ensure your script doesn't get removed when your theme is updated (plenty of resources on how to do this). Create a folder in here called js for tidiness.

EDIT: I think it will be easiest for you to upload your script to: /wp-content/themes/Divi/js folder, and then you can access your script like: `<script src="http://www.adminprofi.com/wp-content/themes/Divi/js/yourscriptname.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have done all of the following and I am recieving the same type of error just with the new location. Is there anything special I have to do for srcing files in html within wordpress?

Comment: Hi @JoeNordling . I don't think that you've set up the child theme correctly. I visited your site and http://www.adminprofi.com/wp-content/themes/ returns a blank page (exists as a directory), but http://www.adminprofi.com/wp-content/themes/child throws a 404 which it wouldn't if the directory existed. If you have set it up, please ensure that you don't have any erroneous htaccess files that could be blocking access to this directory.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by htaccess files?

Comment: Hi @JoeNordling I've updated the answer with a simpler solution. Hopefully this helps. Please mark as the answer if it does. Please note in the long run you should setup a child theme as previously suggested. Thanks.